# Code Metrics in UWP is throwing Assembly reference error (Windows.Phone.PhoneContract)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

An error occurred while calculating code metrics for target file '[...]' in project [...]. The following error was encountered while reading module '[...]': Assembly reference cannot be resolved: Windows.Phone.PhoneContract, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null."

Comment: Have you tried to Restore NuGet Packages(right click the solution - > select `Restore` option) ?

Comment: I restored NuGet packages using Nuget package manager console. But still i'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. Fixed it as follows:

Right click on References in your project, go to Add Reference, Universal Windows, Extensions, and tick Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP.

Comment: Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP is added earlier itself. But facing same issue